# Issue with the update cluase

Tags: sql-update, teradata

I am facing one issue in the update clause. I am trying to do the below:

```
update AM1 from  DB.AM_7541 AM1,
(sel  distinct TRIM(SB.LCDBDN) NEID, trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno) LCDMNO,
AM.Netw_equip 
from 
DB1.PLTL SB
inner join DB.AM_7541 AM
on  trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno)=AM.accs_meth_num
where SB.LOAD_DATE in  ( sel max(load_date),lcdmno,lcdbdn from DB1.PLTL where lcdmno not like ' ' and lcdmno is not null  group by lcdmno, lcdbdn)
and SB.LCDBDN not like ''

) der
set Netw_equip=der.NEID
where AM1.accs_meth_num=der.lcdmno
```

I have to take the max(load_dt) grouped on lcdmno and lcdbdn.
I am getting error like too many expressions in the select clause.

Can you please help me on this.

Checked for dups:

```
sel NEID, LCDMNO, COUNT(*) from
(

sel  distinct TRIM(SB.LCDBDN) NEID, trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno) LCDMNO,
AM.Netw_equip 
from 
DB1.PLTL SB
inner join DB.AM_7541 AM
on  trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno)=AM.accs_meth_num
where SB.LOAD_DATE in  ( sel max(load_date),lcdmno,lcdbdn from DB1.PLTL where lcdmno not like ' ' and lcdmno is not null  group by lcdmno, lcdbdn)
and SB.LCDBDN not like '')
group by 1,2 
having count(*)>1
```

--- 0 rows
Thanks,
Amit

Comment: You must remove `NEID` when you check for dups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explaining, you return three columns in the Subquery but compare to a single row only.

Either rewrite using a Correlated Subquery or a multi-column Subquery:

```
update AM1 from  DB.AM_7541 AM1,
 ( sel  distinct TRIM(SB.LCDBDN) NEID, 
        trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno) LCDMNO,
        AM.Netw_equip 
   from DB1.PLTL SB
   inner join DB.AM_7541 AM
   on  trim( leading '0' from sb.lcdmno)=AM.accs_meth_num
   where (SB.LOAD_DATE, sb.lcdmno, sb.lcdbdn) in
    (
      sel max(load_date),lcdmno,lcdbdn from DB1.PLTL 
      where lcdmno not like ' ' 
        and lcdmno is not null  
      group by lcdmno, lcdbdn
    )
   and SB.LCDBDN not like ''
 ) der
set Netw_equip=der.NEID
where AM1.accs_meth_num=der.lcdmno
```

Btw, applying some formatting really simplifies reading/understanding a query.

Comment: I have never seen `WHERE ... IN` with multiple columns, good to know +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Oracle supports it, too. Easier to write than a Correlated Subquery...

Comment: Thanks a lot Dnoeth..I was able to figure that out..However, I am getting target row updated by multiple source rows.. i checked the inner qyuery for dups i couldn't find any.. also i have used distinct. Can there be any other issue?

Comment: @user3901666: There must be multiple rows returned per `lcdmno`. Hard to tell without knowing your data & keys.